# Formatting time in javascript

Tags: reactjs, datetime, time, format

I am having some trouble correctly formatting a string into a viable datetime that I can use in a table (must be in a time/datetime/non-string format to sort correctly). The field is called `avg_runtime`. The API call returns something like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "01",
        "avg_runtime": "0:05:12.026100",
        "avg_runtime_seconds": 312.0261,
        "file_name": "myFile1",

    },
    {
        "id": "02",
        "avg_runtime": "0:10:03.936321",
        "avg_runtime_seconds": 603.936321,
        "file_name": "myFile2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I added a second field to the backend that returns `avg_runtime_seconds` as a decimal in seconds. One of the challenges is that, in some instances, the return value is days, not just hh:mm:ss, but includes days, like this: `9 days, 17:30:02.813297`. This is a problem in sorting as 9 days, 17:30:02.813297`sorts out of order with`11 days, 2:43:52.300138` (I am using Material UI DataGrid functionality for sorting). So I need to convert these strings into a datetime or some non-string value that be properly sorted. Here's how I currently format values in my API call:

```
  async function getData() {
    await axios
        .get(`https://myapi.com/${ runmode }/products`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        })
        .then((response) =>{
            var this_data = response.data.data;
            setData(
                this_data.map((x) => {
                    return {
                        id: parseInt(`${x.product_id}`),
                        file_name: `${x.file_name}`,
                        avg_runtime: `${x.avg_runtime}`,
                        avg_runtime_seconds: `${x.last_rundate}`   
                    }
                })
            );
            setValidationList(
                tthis_data.map((x) => x.product_id)
            )
            setLoadingData(false);
        });
}
```

I've tried using `avg_runtime: new Date(`${x.avg_runtime}`).toDateString(),` but that returns `Invalid Date`. How can I format this value into a usable (and sortable) time/datetime format?

UPDATE: I was able to utilize Value Getter as suggested below, but it still would not sort correctly, even using numeric values. I found what seems to be the source of the error. While the decimal for the avg_runtime_seconds is set to 6 places, the sorting doesn't seem to take the overall value into consideration. Look at the Avg Runtime Seconds difference between 9 days, 17 hrs, 45 mins, compared to 2hrs, 21 mins. The sorting seems to be based on the character placement, rather than taking into consideration where the decimal is located. Anything that would help fix this?

[image]

Comment: If you're using MUI Datagrid, could you reference the `avg_runtime_seconds` field for sorting but display the `avg_runtime` as the label using a [value getter](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-getter)? That way your label doesn't dictate the underlying value. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sutherland-lxq9lt?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Hmmm, that is an interesting idea. So even though I display the string value, when it comes to sorting, it sorts by the avg_runtime_seconds value which is not, itself displayed?

Comment: Yep! That's the idea behind it. I'm not familiar with the API of MUI but quickly looking at their docs, it looks like there are several ways to render a cell. I would recommend taking a look through the various options they offer to determine what's best for your needs. [Here's an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-smoke-vns318) using [renderCell](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells) rather than [value getter](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-getter).

Comment: See my updated comments. It seems the issue is still present, even with numeric values.

Comment: Do you mind posting the full code of the DataGrid including the full dataset?

Comment: It will take some time to put something together as this is not a public API. I'll try to put together an approximation of it. The data, and columns are also fed to the DataGrid component (or the component in which the DataGrid lives) from a parent component, so its a little more complicated than that. Let me try and put something in CodePen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251555/discussion-between-dennis-martinez-and-gwydion93).

Comment: OK, I just created some data and code in CodeSandbox that perfectly illustrates what's going on here. Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pond-ey49we

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a difficult issue to resolve. The first thing I had to do was get a field with a numeric value that I could reference when sorting. I had the avg_runtime in seconds as a float, but the `@mui` DataGrid only seemed to work properly with whole numbers so I converted them using Math.ceil (round up). I also noticed that the original suggestion to use [value getter](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-getter) seemed to still sort by the value that is displayed in the DataGrid. I tried another suggestion using [GridRenderCellParams](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pond-ey49we?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1589). This worked and I created a sandbox to test it. The below code is what I used, but here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-pond-ey49we?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1589) to a better visualization of the solution. *Note-the avg_runtime_sconds values have already been changed to whole integers below instead of using `Math.ceil`.

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRenderCellParams } from "@mui/x-data-grid";

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 90 },
  {
    field: "file_name",
    headerName: "File Name",
    width: 150,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "avg_runtime",
    headerName: "Avg Runtime Orig",
    width: 150,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: "avg_runtime_seconds",
    headerName: "Avg Runtime Ref Secs",
    width: 150,
    editable: true,
    renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => (
      <div>{params.row.avg_runtime}</div>
    )
  }
];

const rows = [
  {
    id: "01",
    avg_runtime: "0:05:12.026100",
    avg_runtime_seconds: 312,
    file_name: "myFile1"
  },
  {
    id: "02",
    avg_runtime: "0:10:03.936321",
    avg_runtime_seconds: 603,
    file_name: "myFile2"
  },
  {
    id: "03",
    avg_runtime: "9 days, 17:45:04.823807",
    avg_runtime_seconds: 841670,
    file_name: "myFile3"
  },
  {
    id: "04",
    avg_runtime: "11 days, 3:01:15.710670",
    avg_runtime_seconds: 961275,
    file_name: "myFile4"
  }
];

export default function DataGridDemo() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={5}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```